# Java: Why am I required to initialize a primitive local variable?

Tags: java, primitive

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float f;
        System.out.println(f);
    }
}
```

The print statement causes the following compile-time error,

> The local variable f may not have been initialized

If primitives in Java already have a [default value (float = 0.0f)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), why am I required to define one?

---

## Edit:

So, this works

```
public class Foo {
    float f;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Foo().f);
    }
}
```

Thanks, everyone!

Comment: re the edit: yes that works, but promoting a local to a field to avoid initialization might not be a reasonable example :-)

Comment: @fvu, it's an example, so it serves some purpose. :D

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Because it's a local variable. This is why nothing is assigned to it :

> Local variables are slightly different; the compiler never assigns a
>   default value to an uninitialized local variable. If you cannot
>   initialize your local variable where it is declared, make sure to
>   assign it a value before you attempt to use it. Accessing an
>   uninitialized local variable will result in a compile-time error.

**Edit: Why does Java raise this compilation error ?**
If we look at the [`IdentifierExpression.java`](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/tools/tree/IdentifierExpression.java) class file, we will find this block :

```
...
if (field.isLocal()) {
            LocalMember local = (LocalMember)field;
            if (local.scopeNumber < ctx.frameNumber && !local.isFinal()) {
                env.error(where, "invalid.uplevel", id);
            }
            if (!vset.testVar(local.number)) {
                env.error(where, "var.not.initialized", id);
                vset.addVar(local.number);
            }
            local.readcount++;
        }
...
```

As stated (`if (!vset.testVar(local.number)) {`), the JDK checks (with `testVar`) if the variable is assigned ([`Vset`'s source code](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/17986236/) where we can find `testVar` code). If not, it raises the error `var.not.initialized` from a [properties file](http://web.mit.edu/java_v1.1.6/arch/sun4x_55/lib/javac.properties) :

```
...
javac.err.var.not.initialized=\
    Variable {0} may not have been initialized.
...
```

[Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Comment: This doesn't really *explain* "why", does it?

Answer (score 18):

In fact, the compiler *does not* assign a default value to your `float f`, because in this case it is a local variable -- and not a field:

> Local variables are slightly different; the compiler never assigns a default value to an uninitialized local variable. If you cannot initialize your local variable where it is declared, make sure to assign it a value before you attempt to use it. Accessing an uninitialized local variable will result in a compile-time error.

Answer (score 8):

Class fields (non-`final` ones anyway) are initialized to default values.  Local variables are not.

> It's not always necessary to assign a value when a field is declared. Fields that are declared but not initialized will be set to a reasonable default by the compiler.

So a (non-`final`) field like `f` in

```
class C {
  float f;
}
```

will be initialized to `0f` but the local variable `f` in

```
void myMethod() {
  float f;
}
```

will not be.

Local variables are treated differently from fields by the language.  Local variables have a well-scoped lifetime, so any use before initialization is probably an error.  Fields do not so the default initialization is often convenient.

Answer (score 5):

Actually local variables are stored in stack.Hence there is a chance of taking any old value
present for the local variable.It is a big challenge for security reason..Hence java says you have to initialise a local varible before use.

Answer (score 2):

Hi  guys solution is simple.
the values that are stored on the heap memory are initialized by the compiler based datatype but local variables are stored on stack memory so we have to inialize it explictly.