# The local variable gcd may not have been initialized

Tags: java

I have the following code where variable `gcd` is inside the gcd() function and this is showing the error:

> The local variable gcd may not have been initialized.

The code is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GreatestCommonDivisorMethod {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Enter two numbers");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num1 = input.nextInt();
        int num2 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("the gcd of the " + num1 + " and " + num2 + " is " + gcd(num1,num2));
    }

    public static int gcd(int n1, int n2) {
        int gcd ;
        for (int n = 1; n <= n1 && n <= n2 ; n++) {
            if (n1 % n == 0 && n2 % n == 0)
                gcd = n;
        }
        return gcd;

    }
}
```

Why `gcd` should be initialized?

Comment: Control may not go inside the for loop, so you have to initialize it

Comment: Thanks for your answer ,but why it may not go inside the loop ,could you tell me the reason?@Subhiksh

Answer (score 3):

Essentially, because of the way Java works, `gcd` needs to be declared at some point.

Your method declares `int gcd` but never assigns it a value except inside your if-statement. There is the possible case where your if-statement never gets entered, because the boolean statement inside it never evaluates to true. In that possible case, there would be a problem, as `return gcd;` would execute even though no value has been assigned to it. Java does not want this to occur and is warning you.

You probably want to set a default value in case it doesn't find a gcd. This value would obviously be 1, so declare it as such: `int gcd = 1;`.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -4):

- The first thing is every variable must be initialised before it is used.
- Compiler does this to make sure that at the time of the execution or using the variable in the program there is atleast one value in the variable .
- To avoid **compile-time error.** this is used.
- In your case if the value **n1** and **n2** are 0 , then the control will not go into the for loop and the **gcd** will not be initialised . While returning the gcd value there will be *compile-time error.*.
- I would also like to point out this part from *java docs* ,

  > Local variables are slightly different; the compiler never assigns a default value to an uninitialized local variable. If you cannot initialize your local variable where it is declared, make sure to assign it a value before you attempt to use it. Accessing an uninitialized local variable will result in a compile-time error.

  *you can get the complete docs in [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) link.*

  *Credit-[SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165485/java-why-am-i-required-to-initialize-a-primitive-local-variable)*

  This says that as your gcd is a local variable thats why it is not initialised with default value.
- Therefore you have to initialise the variable.
- This is what you should do-

  ```
  public static int gcd(int n1, int n2) {
  int gcd = 0;
  for (int n = 1; n <= n1 && n <= n2 ; n++) {
  if (n1 % n == 0 && n2 % n == 0)
       gcd = n;
  }
  return gcd;

  }
  ```

  > int gcd = 0;

Hope this answer helps you.

Comment: Primitives cannot be null

Comment: I completely disagree with you.  see my edited answer @RaphaelRoth.

Comment: No seriously, **primitives cannot be `null`.**

Comment: this primitive which is local is null . see the edited answer . you will find your answer .

Comment: the docs specifically says the words which will make you understand what you are doing wrong. and dont say anything if you are not clear . it says ---- Local variables are slightly different; the compiler never assigns a default value to an uninitialized local variable. If you cannot initialize your local variable where it is declared, make sure to assign it a value before you attempt to use it. Accessing an uninitialized local variable will result in a compile-time error.

Comment: if @Makoto needs the proof for it , go to this link and study it.  
 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: @RaphaelRoth did you saw the docs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: @SagarNayak, it seems that you do not understand what is `null`

Comment: Local variables are slightly different; the compiler never assigns a default value to an uninitialized local variable. If you cannot initialize your local variable where it is declared, make sure to assign it a value before you attempt to use it. Accessing an uninitialized local variable will result in a compile-time error. 

this is what the java docs says , link - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

have a look at it @DenisZinkovskiy