# Adding edge weights to a 2-d array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, graph

Im trying to add edge weights to a 2-d array. im looped through the graph edges, then looped through the nodes and comparing the 2 to find the index of the head node and the tail node, then trying to add that to the array. But its telling me my variables arent initialized. Any ideas?

```
        int head;
        int tail;
        for (int i = 0; i < g.edgeList.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < g.nodeList.size(); j++) {
                if (g.nodeList.get(j) == g.edgeList.get(i).head) {
                    head = g.nodeList.indexOf(j);
                }
                if (g.nodeList.get(j) == g.edgeList.get(i).tail) {
                    tail = g.nodeList.indexOf(j);
                }
                W[head][tail] = Integer.parseInt(g.edgeList.get(i).label);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Change your int declarations to `int head = 0; int tail = 0;`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165485/java-why-am-i-required-to-initialize-a-primitive-local-variable