# Writing a program to check password for certain things

Tags: java

Im writing a program to check for values in a password given by the user. I have posted the code below and I think its all good I'm just confused on how the syntax for the boolean check in the if statement should be checked. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
public class PasswordValidation
{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Password: ");
    String password = stdin.next();
    int passwordLength = password.length();

    String pCheck = "password";

    boolean capital;
    boolean lowercase;
    boolean number;
    boolean specialChar;
    char check;
    for(int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++){
        check = password.charAt(i);
        if(Character.isDigit(check)){
            number = true;
        }else if (Character.isUpperCase(check)){
            capital = true;
        }else if (Character.isLowerCase(check)){
            lowercase = true;
        }else{
            specialChar = true;
        }
    }
    if(number = true && capital = true && lowercase = true && specialChar = false && password.length() >= 8 && password.toLowerCase().contains(pCheck.toLowerCase())){
        System.out.println("Password is good");
```

Comment: `number = true` is an assignment and changes the variable value, but `number == true` is a comparison.

Comment: I've tried that as well and I'm just getting a syntax error that variable 'number' has not been initialized

Comment: Then set it to false when you declare it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165485/java-why-am-i-required-to-initialize-a-primitive-local-variable

Comment: For security reasons it's best to keep passwords in an char[] rather than a String.

Answer (score 1):

you have some errors, to check equality of value you need to use `==` not `=`

```
number == true && capital == true && lowercase == true ...
```

or better you can do this

```
number && capital && lowercase ...
```

because they are just booleans